# Nothing appears on console in chrome,taking information from form

Tags: javascript, java, string, google-chrome, web

I'm creating a simple string reverse project.

I want the user to enter input, then that input will be displayed below the text box in reverse order.

```
<form id = "frm1">
<input type="text" id="userInput"=> give me input</input>
<button onclick="strRev()">Submit</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">



    function strRev(str){

        str = document.getElementById("userInput").toString().value;
        console.log(str);

        var originalStr = str.split("");

        console.log(originalStr);
        var finalArray = [];
        var j = 0;
        for(i = originalStr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
            finalArray[j] = originalStr[i];
            j++;
        }

        for(k = 0; k <finalArray.length; k++){
            document.write(finalArray[k]);

        }


    }


</script>
```

[When pressing submit, the information in the box is what should be reversed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sptIJ.png)

Nothing happens on submit and nothing appears in console to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
str = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 onclick="strRev()"
```

and you are calling

```
function strRev(str) // function with one argument, must be showing error in console
```

Answer (score 0):

Add type="button" in your button input, that way the form won't refresh

```
<button type=button onclick="strRev()">Submit</button>
```

You will probably be able to continue solving your other problems after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your html here `<input type="text" id="userInput"=>`

it should be `<input type="text" id="userInput">`

also fetching the value of input should be like this

`str = document.getElementById("userInput").value;`

After applying these changes you will see the output in console